# Drawing a bar graph in C

Tags: arrays, c, graph

The user should input the elements of an array(maximum 20 of them). The task is to draw a bar graph using |, *, and - by using these elements. A line of minuses should be drawn instead of zero, and * instead of last member of an array. If the number is 3 for example, two | and one * above them should be drawn. The problem that I have with my code is that it sometimes takes too long to execute, draws one instead of two minuses between the array elements, and sometimes doesn't draw the line with minuses.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

   int main() {
   int n[20];
   int i,j,counter=0,input=0,min,max;
   printf("Elements of the array: \n");
   while(input!=1000){
        scanf("%d", &input);
        n[counter]=input;
        counter++;
  }
  counter--;
  min=n[0];
  max=n[0];
  for(i=1;i<counter;i++){
      if(n[i]>max) max=n[i];
      if(n[i]<min) min=n[i];
   }
 for(i=0;i<max-min+1;i++){
     for(j=0;j<2*counter;j++){
         if(j%2==0 && n[j/2]==max-i) printf("*");
         else if(i==max) printf("-");
         else if(j%2==0 && n[j/2]>0 && i<max && n[j/2]>max-i) printf("|");
         else if(j%2==0 && n[j/2]<0 && i>max && n[j/2]<max-i) printf("|");
         else printf(" ");
      }
    printf("\n");
    }
   }//  Input:4 -3 7 0 -1 1000 Expected output:
        *        
        |        
        |        
  *     |        
  |     |        
  |     |        
  |     |        
  ---------*-----
     |        *  
     |           
     *           
     My output:
      *     
      |     
      |     
  *   |     
  |   |     
  |   |     
  |   |     
  ------*---
      |     * 
      |       
      *       
 Input: 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 Expected output:
 *                       *                                          
 |  *                 *  |                                          
 |  |  *           *  |  |                                          
 |  |  |  *     *  |  |  |                                          
 |  |  |  |  *  |  |  |  |                                          
 ---------------------------
  My output:
  *               * 
  | *           * | 
  | | *       * | | 
  | | | *   * | | | 
  | | | | * | | | | //
```

Comment: You should start with `min = 0`, `max = 0`, and `for (i=0;` since you always want the zero line to be included in the chart.

Comment: also change the `%2`, `/2` and `2*` to 3 to get that nicer spacing.